# Dealing with spaces and "weird" characters in column names with dplyr::rename()

Tags: r, dplyr

I have table with difficult headers like this:

```
  Subject  Cat Nbr  Title       Instruction..Mode!
1 XYZ      101      Intro I     ONLINE
2 XYZ      102      Intro II    CAMPUS
3 XYZ      135      Advanced    CAMPUS
```

I would like to rename the columns with `dplyr::rename()`

```
df %>%
 rename(subject = Subject, 
        code = Cat Nbr, 
        title = title, 
        mode = Instruction..Mode!)
```

But I am getting an `Error: unexpected symbol in:`

How might I reconcile this?

Comment: `names(df) <- c("subject", "code", "title", "mode")`

Comment: Yes, let us not become entirely dependent on the hadleyverse for everything. Base R FTW...

Comment: Can't you just wrap the name in back ticks?

Comment: I know how to base rename columns. I want to rename with dplyr::rename() to keep everything consistent and readable (for my boss).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To refer to variables that contain non-standard characters or start with a number, wrap the name in back ticks, e.g., `` `Instruction..Mode!` ``

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! It is very upsetting that this is still required when there should be several better ways to do this.